# How to Ensure Full Page Content Coverage in PDF Generated from URLs Using pdfkit in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, python-re

I'm working on a Python script to fetch URLs from a website, convert them into a PDF, and then process the PDF to create a new PDF and text file. The new files should have empty pages, empty lines, and illegal characters removed. However, I've encountered an issue where the content in the generated PDF only covers a small portion of each page, and I'm unsure how to adjust the settings to ensure the content utilizes the full page.

Here's the part of my script that deals with the PDF generation and processing:

```py
import os
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pdfkit
import pdfplumber
import re

# Convert the list of URLs to a single PDF
temp_pdf_path = os.path.join(output_dir, 'temp.pdf')

# Function to process PDF text and remove empty pages/lines
def process_pdf_text(input_pdf_path):
    writer = PdfWriter()
    output_text = ""

    with open(input_pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PdfReader(file)
        for page in reader.pages:
            text = page.extract_text()
            cleaned_text = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', text).strip()
            if cleaned_text:  # Check if the page is not empty
                output_text += cleaned_text + "\n\n"
                writer.add_page(page)

    return output_text, writer

# ... [Code to save the new PDF and text file] ...

# Uncommenting the removal of temp.pdf
os.remove(temp_pdf_path)

print(f"Processed PDF and text files saved: {new_pdf_path}, {new_txt_path}")
```

***Steps involved in the code:***

1. Import necessary libraries/modules, including os, requests, urljoin,
   BeautifulSoup, pdfkit, pdfplumber, re, PdfReader, and PdfWriter.
2. Define the output_dir variable, which is assumed to be the directory
   where you want to save the output files.
3. Assuming that new_pdf_path and new_txt_path are defined earlier in
   your code, these variables represent the paths to the output PDF and
   text files.
4. Create the temp_pdf_path variable, which represents the path to a
   temporary PDF file.
5. Define the process_pdf_text function, which extracts text from a
   PDF, removes empty pages/lines, and returns the cleaned text along
   with a PdfWriter object containing the non-empty pages.
6. Perform other operations within the code (not shown) to create the
   new PDF and text files.
7. Uncomment the removal of the temp.pdf file using
   os.remove(temp_pdf_path).
8. Finally, print a message indicating the paths where the processed
   PDF and text files are saved.

The generated PDFs have their content squeezed into a small area of the page. I need the content to be readable and cover the full page appropriately. Also, I'm removing empty pages, lines, and any illegal characters in the text extraction process.

How to adjust the `pdfkit` settings or recommend a different approach to ensure the content covers the entire page properly in the generated PDF?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML output to ensure that's not where you need to focus?